# Python Ensemble VotingClassifier for regression

Tags: python, ensemble-learning

I want to build an Ensemble method to predict sales. Suppose I use estimators `Linear Regression`, `Decision Tree Regression` and `ARIMA`.

I decided to take the mean of the above estimators to be my predicted value. Can I use the `VotingClassifier` class to build this ensemble? or does it work only for classification problems?

Is there some other library in `python` for combining different regression estimators (not classification and it can't be the same estimator like in bagging regression)

Answer (score 0):

Simply make predictions and take an average of them.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#voting-classifier

For classification there are two ways:

**hard voting** - class which was predicted by most models is selectes;

**soft voting** - each model predicts probabilities, classes with the highest probability are chosen.